# Pattern matching using awk until colon

Tags: unix, awk

Sorry I'm struggling to phrase the question in google so I can't really find threads that help :(

My text file is as follows:

```
John Smith: Favourite book is Harry Potter
Jane Ayre: Doesn't know how to read
...
```

All names will be until the colon only, and have a space between given name and family name.

I am trying to write an awk script to match the names (before the colon), go to the next line and do the same, then print the number of matches. However I am not sure how to pattern match the strings until colon.

My regex expression for names are:

```
john|adam|james|charles smith|ayre|brooke|brown
```

I've tried

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{tolower($0)} $0 ~ /john|adam|james|charles/ {sum+=1} END{print sum}
```

I know this is terribly wrong, how can I fix this?

Thank you!

EDIT: The name ONLY works if the string is an exact match, i.e. John will not match with Johnson, and only match with the given name (first word).

Comment: Should `john` in  your regexp match `Phil John:` or `Phil Johnson:` or `Johnson Philips:` in the input? Please [edit] your example to included cases where partial matches and/or matches on the wrong part of the name can occur to better show us your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this approach with field separator as `:`:

```sh
awk -F: 'tolower($1) ~ /john|adam|james|charles/ {sum+=1} END {print sum+0}' file

1
```